# Get the url present in window.history.back() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angularjs I have created a back button for my application using the command **window.history.back()**

```
$scope.goBack = function() {
    $window.history.back();
};
```

and I want that the back button will not be displayed in the first page i.e. index.html. So, I want the url that is present in **window.history.back()** so that I can check that if it is index.html then I can **ng-hide** it.

**So is there any way so that I can get the relative url to which window.history.back() will redirect ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: aren't u using Any server side Programming?

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can make the browser go back the the previous page, but you can't find out what that page is.

If that was possible, that could be used to spy on what sites people were visiting before.

Comment: then how can i get the url of the page, that command is redirecting me to??

Comment: @user2434139 `but you can't find out what that page is`

Comment: `Is there any way I could manually store the history and then could go back accordingly`

Comment: @Anindya: Possibly, but then you would have to incorporate that into every link in the site, and also have code to catch when the user is using the back button. That seems like overkill just to find out what page you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.referrer`, that should fit your needs.